# Find count of numbers containing 4 and 7 within range without using static array

Tags: c, algorithm

Unlucky Numbers

There are few numbers considered to be unlucky (those whose only digits are 4 and 7).
Our goal is to find count of such numbers in the range of positive integers `a` and `b`.

#### Example 1

Input: a = 10, b = 20
Output: 0

#### Example 2

Input: a = 30, b = 50
Output: 2 (44, 47)

Below is the code I tried out using a static array approach, wherein I calculate all possible unlucky numbers for a 32-bit integer initially. This is done in O(n) and later a sequential scan helps obtain the count which is again an O(n) operation.

```c
#define MAX_UNLUCKY 1022
static int unlucky[MAX_UNLUCKY];  
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    int i, j, k;  
    int a, b, factor;  
    printf("Enter the numbers : \n");  
    scanf("%d",&a);  
    scanf("%d",&b);  
    unlucky[0] = 4;  
    unlucky[1] = 7;  
    factor = 10;  
    k = 1;  
    for(i = 2; i < MAX_UNLUCKY; ++i) 
        unlucky[i] = unlucky[(i >> 1) - 1]*factor + unlucky[k ^= 1];  
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_UNLUCKY;++i) 
        if (unlucky[i] > a) break;  
    for (k = i; k < MAX_UNLUCKY;++k) { 
        if (unlucky[k] > b) break;
        printf("Unlukcy numbers = %d\n", unlucky[k]);  
    }  
    printf ("Total Number of Unlucky numbers in this range is %d\n", k-i);  
    return (0);
}
```

Is there a better approach to solve this without the help of a static array ?

Comment: Minor optimization note: Your approach `k = 1;` [...] `+ unlucky[k ^= 1];` to generate the sequence `4,7,4,7,4...` is using an array lookup which you can remove using something like `k = 7;` [...] `+ (k = 11 - k)`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible in `log(n)^k` time&space(with small constant k, but I'm too lazy to calculate the actual k). You only need to calculate the count, you don't need to enumerate them all. You can use that there are 2^n unlucky numbers below the number 10^n.

Comment: @Luchian: log(N) to be exact ^_^

Comment: I believe the solution is suggested is in O(1)

Comment: @yi_H - no this is not a homework. I came across this on a website and tried to solve it. Is there a protocol on this forum that I have to be explicit in mentioning it is 'not a homework', if so please say so

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following:

How many numbers are there between

```
0x100 and 0x111?

100,101,110,111 ( 4 = 0x111 - 0x100 + 1 )
```

That's exactly how many unlucky numbers there are between 744 and 777 (744,747,774,777).

Now:

700 and 800 have the same number of unlucky numbers between them as 744 and 777.
744 is the smallest unlucky number greater than 700 and 777 is the greatest unlucky number smaller than 800.

No need to generate numbers, just substraction.

For cases like a = 10, b = 800, first find your number for 10-100 and then 100-800 (because you'll be counting some numbers twice):

For 10-100:

```
a = 44
b = 77

0x11 - 0x00 = 3 + 1 = 4 ( 44,47,74,77 )
```

For 100-800:

```
a = 444
b = 777

0x111 - 0x000 = 7 + 1 = 8 ( 444, 447, 474, 477, 744, 747, 774, 777 )
```

So between 10 and 800: 4+8 = 12 numbers, which is also correct.

This is also O(1) time & space if you find the auxiliary numbers efficiently, which shouldn't be too hard...

Comment: If you're splitting it up by digit, then you aren't going to be getting O(1), since you'll be doing Θ(log(n)) computations. That said, I can think of two simple tricks to get around this issue.

Comment: Please share :). Also, let's assume for simplicity limited number size. I mean, if you want to go all theoretical, addition is O(n) - since you have to add digit by digit :P

Comment: You have to admit though, not a bad idea... :)

Comment: There are exactly 2^n unlucky numbers with n digits (and 2^(n+1)-2 with at most n digits), so you can quickly compute the values in the intermediate range. A simple way to realise this is to add 1 to the MSB (e.g. 0x111 -> 0x1011, 0x000 -> 0x100) and then just subtract the two endpoints. However, I'm certain it isn't possible to compute the next/previous unlucky number in less than O(log(n)) like you say can be done.

Comment: @Luchian - I did try this method initially by equating them to the binary method. But then it is very quick to come to the low and high range - calculating the intermediary numbers is quite a tedious task :) Then later the above laid out recursive solution struck me.